# Are community members disciplined over abusing other community members elsewhere using links to this site?

Tags: discussion

Suppose a community member uses another site to abuse another community member, but using links to this site, such as to posts and profiles etc. Should that member be brought to the attention of the moderators?

Answer (score 10):

Under the circumstances stated, no. When we're considering disciplinary action, we don't care about anything that has happened outside this site ([Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/), [Physics Meta](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com), the [main site chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71) and [its alternate](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13775), and possibly but not necessarily any other associated chat rooms). Even if someone is linking to this site, that doesn't make it any business of ours. We can't and don't control what people link to from elsewhere on the web.

Any disciplinary action that may be necessary for something posted on another site is the responsibility of the people in charge on that site.

To be clear, we do care about things that have happened *on this site*. If information posted elsewhere on the web helps the moderators understand something that is happening *here*, then you certainly can bring that to our attention. Use a private channel: a custom flag, or if flagging isn't sufficient, you can ask to open a private chat room with the mods.

In public - a meta post - it's a little more touchy. Technically it's not against the rules to mention things that go on elsewhere on the web, but if you're doing so in an attempt to shame the person whose behavior on another site is being discussed, that may qualify as a personal attack, which is definitely not appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

Users will not be disciplined for activities off-site. As David said,  `Any disciplinary action that may be necessary for something posted on another site is the responsibility of the authorities on that site.`

But there is nothing wrong with bringing it to our notice, as long as it is done *privately* (custom flag a post of theirs or use [this form](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/other)). Bringing it up on meta will cause unnecessary drama, and may be considered as a personal attack; an attempt to shame the user.

Issues between two users on other sites may have repercussions here, so bringing it to our notice lets us investigate the situation on this side of the fence (look for revenge voting, offensive comments, etc).

While bringing it to our notice, you need not even mention the site where you saw the user abusing the others, it's better if you just mention which two users are being talked about.

**Bottom line: Off-site activities alone do not merit any punishment, but you should bring them to our notice privately so we can investigate it on this site.**

Comment: I don't understand what sort of repercussions off-site behavior would have here. We don't punish for it, and I really think it's better if we avoid any involvement with things happening on other sites.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: If two users are fighting off-site, there is a chance that they may start to do so here. We just need to keep a watch, that's all.

Comment: Yeah, and once they start fighting here, then we care. Before that happens... I wouldn't tell anyone else they can't or shouldn't be interested, but I'm not.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: Point is, what if they have already started fighting here and we haven't noticed? We can at least check for angry comment discussions/vote anomalies.

Comment: Yeah, but all we need there is a tip of the form "Watch out for X and Y going at each other." It doesn't need to reference anything on another site.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: True; edited :)

Comment: For a minute I thought I was reading a brief Shog or GraceNote post, this is well written, albeit missing a little something ... Shoggish.

Comment: @jcolebrand: I feel honored that you think that I write like them :D Re:Shoggish -- Nobody but the Shog can be Shoggish. Even people copy-pasting Shog scripture cannot reach his levels of awesome Shogginess!

Answer (score -1):

I think you should absolutely report it, but keep in mind that, as David says, mods can only take action for whatever happens on the site and not for what happens outside.

That said, it is obvious that people having arguments off-site is likely to have consequences on-site, and any warning is useful.

For example: if one person accuses another off site of having sock puppets here, it's still relevant to *us*! If someone is a known troll outside of this community, it's still relevant to *us*! Etcetera.

Bottom line is, warn mods *in private*, via a flag or in a private chat room, or [contact support](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/help/other) if you think that something bad is happening out the site but about the site.

Please do not post on meta though, to avoid unnecessary drama.